# Does "免费" mean "free" in terms of price?

Tags: meaning

Does "免费" mean "free" when we are talking about price? Or is it like "freedom"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"免费" means "free of charge".

"免" means "exempt" or "no".

"费" means "costs" or "fees".

"smoke free" or "smoking-free" means "不可吸烟", "无烟区".

Answer (score 4):

["免费"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%8D%E8%B2%BB) is "free" in terms of price.

"免" means "exempt"; "费" means "costs" or "fees". "Exempt from costs" = "free".

["自由"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E7%94%B1) is "free" as in freedom/liberty.

Answer (score -1):

It's "Free". It's not like "Freedom".